# html table will not center align inside div that is a dojox/layout/contentpane left region

Tags: html, css, dojo

I've got an html table inside a dojox/layout/ContentPane left region div.  I can't get the table to center inside of the div.  I've tried using: margin: 0 auto; in the css styling of the table, but the table is always left aligned.  The table contains a dijit/layout/TabContainer with content panes that are populated with google charts (maybe these are impacting the layout?).  Below is my code, any suggestions appreciated.  In the screen shot the table border is in yellow and the div border is in orange on the left side of the image

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox/layout/ContentPane" id="FormLeft" data-dojo-props="splitter: false, region:'left'">
        <div id="FormLeft">
            <table class="TblPieCharts">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/TabContainer" class="TCPieChart" id="tcTickets">
                            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="Categories" id="DACat"></div>
                            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="Priorities" id="DAPriority"></div>
                            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="Types" id="DAType"></div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><div id="DAFYE" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
/*style for content pane*/
#FormLeft {
width: 25%;
background-color:black;
border-width: 6px;
border-color:orange;
}
/*style for table holding pie charts*/
.TblPieCharts {
margin: 0 auto;
align-content:center;
background-color: yellow;
color: white;

}
/*style for tab container*/
.TCPieChart {
width: 350px;
height: 300px;
background-color: black;
margin: 0 auto;
border-width: 0px;
}
/*style for pie chart*/
#DACat {
width: 350px;
height: 250px;
background-color: black;
margin: 0 auto;
border-width: 0px;
}
```

[image]

Thanks

Pete

Answer (score 0):

You can set `text-align: center` to the `td` containing tabcontainer.

Comment: Thanks Rohan.  setting the text-align of the td isnt working for me, but using viewport units (vw, vh) in the css I'm able to get the space filled up enough that centering isnt an issue